# No Output in hciconfig command?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, parrotsec

I'm new to Linux and just started learning Ethical Hacking. I wanted to configure Bluetooth devices.I entered Command `hciconfig` but i cannot see any output or result.I'm Using ParrotSec on VMware.
Commands I used:

```
sudo apt-get update

service bluetooth start
```

I have also Enabled Bluetooth from my Host System (Windows 10)
When I type command **hciconfig** it gives me no result.
[image]

Help If I am doing something wrong. I'm to this and still learning.Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Edit: i have also used `hciconfig -a` same things happens :(

Answer (score 0):

Only one operating system at a time can control the Bluetooth transceiver. If you wish to use it in a virtual machine, you'll have to configure VMware to pass full control of the BT transceiver (usually an USB device) to the VM.

When you do this, the host OS will be unable to use Bluetooth until the VM is stopped or reconfigured to not use the BT transceiver any more.